# Python count total items in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

So I want to count up all the values together to make a totalItems var which will be printed underneath the list. the output gives me 5 instead of it all being counter up. Can someone explain me why, not just give the right code.

```
stuff = {'coins': 5, 'arrows': 42, 'rope': 1}


def getInvent(inventory):

    itemTotal = 0
    print('Inventory:')
    print(str(stuff['coins']) + '  Coins')
    print(str(stuff['arrows']) + ' Arrows')
    print(str(stuff['rope']) + '  Rope')   

    for k, v in stuff.items():
        itemTotal = itemTotal + v
        print('Total number of items: ' + str(itemTotal)) 
        return itemTotal

getInvent(stuff)
```

Comment: Have you read the code and followed what it does?

Comment: There is indentation problem with your code. `return itemTotal` is inside the for loop and hence after the first iteration `5` is returned and rest are not counted. A simpler code would be - `sum(stuff.values())`.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn the for loop into a one-liner with `sum()` and `dict.values()`:

```
>>> sum(stuff.values())
48
```

**Explanation:**

`stuff.values()` gives you a list of all the values in the dictionary:

```
>>> stuff.values()
[1, 5, 42]
```

`sum()` adds together all items in an iterable (like a list):

```
>>> sum([1, 5, 42])
48
```

**Full example:**

```
stuff = {'coins': 5, 'arrows': 42, 'rope': 1}

def getInvent(inventory):
    print('Inventory:')
    print(str(stuff['coins']) + '  Coins')
    print(str(stuff['arrows']) + ' Arrows')
    print(str(stuff['rope']) + '  Rope')   

    itemTotal = sum(inventory.values())
    print('Total number of items: ' + str(itemTotal)) 
    return itemTotal

getInvent(stuff)
```

Comment: Julien just beat me to this, sum the list of values is the easiest way to do this in a single readable line of code

Comment: Thank you, and I saw something about sum() on stackoverflow, but the thing is, I'm following rules of a book. The rules were not to use sum() since I have not been able to learn that yet.

Answer (score 1):

You should not `return` inside your loop because in that case it returns immediately (in the first iteration of the loop). Instead, put the return outside the loop.

```
for k, v in stuff.items():
    itemTotal = itemTotal + v
    print('Total number of items: ' + str(itemTotal)) 
return itemTotal
```

A function will return immediately when it encounters the `return` statement. So you should ensure that your loop runs in its entirety before returning the value.

Comment: I didn't even notice it! Thank you so much. This is exactly what I searched for!